# mTLS, Openshift route, and reencrypt mode

Tags: openshift, mtls

I'm not a cluster admin and don't want to enable mTLS on all routes/ingress. Just one, for a specific service. So a lot of the "how to enable mTLS on Openshift" doesn't apply.

Anyway, I thought I'd be able to create a route with "reencrypt" mode and the client cert would be part of what it was reencrypting. But I'm not seeing a client cert on the web server and I don't know if that's because it isn't sending it for some reason or the reencrypt is stripping it out.

I can't create a route that isn't reencrypt or edge terminating. I assume edge termination will be even less friendly to client certs.

Anyone any better ideas?